# Do I need to buy a domain before creating a new cPanel in WHM?

Tags: linux, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting, whm

Do I need to buy a domain first before configuring it on the client's WHM?
Yesterday I configured a cPanel account inside the client's WHM  dashboard. I was able to access the site by its IP address. But accessing it by its domain name gives me a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not necessary that you buy or "connect" a domain to a cPanel account.**

By creating a cPanel account with a primary domain you're:

1. Creating a Virtual Host in the Apache / NGINX HTTP server
2. Creating a DNS zone for that domain on the server

If you register a domain and point it by A record (or change its Nameservers) everyone around the world will be able to resolve your domain to the server's IP address.

> I was able to access the site by its IP address

Usually accessing a site on a cPanel server like 1.1.1.1/~$USER/ is using Apache's userdir mod.

Since the domain is already added in a Virtual Host and the HTTP server can serve its content it is not necessary that you have a legitimate domain which is pointed to the server (A rec/Nameservers)

Instead you can edit your hosts file locally, like:

```
## cPanel_Acc_IP your_Domain
1.1.1.1 www.yourDomain.com yourDomain.com
```

*Note: file is present in different locations on different operating systems:

```
## Windows
c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

## Linux
/etc/hosts

#Mac
/etc/hosts OR /etc/private/hosts
```

Then simply access the website. This will make your computer resolve that specific domain to your cPanel account, regardless of whether the domain is registered and pointed.